# How to pass methods to react context api and use them in class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to createa  a context something like below

```
const SocketContext = React.createContext({
    socket:socket,
    loginToZone:(username,password,params,zoneName)=>{
        debugger;

        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

            socket.addEventListener( onLogin, this);
            socket.addEventListener( onLoginError, this);
            socket.send(new LoginRequest(username,password, params,zoneName))
            const onLogin=(evtParams)=>{
                resolve("Login SuccessFull")
    
            }

            const  onLoginError=(evtParams)=>{
               reject("Login failure:" + evtParams.errorMessage);

            }


        })
       

    }



});
```

export default SocketContext;

And I Am trying to use it in my class component

```
class Component
{
static contextType = SocketContext
compoentDidMount()
{
const socketContext=this.context;


}
}
```

And now when I am trying to call the method loginToZone
`socketContext.loginToZone` it throws error

`socketContext.loginToZone is not a function` ,how to do such type of task ,any help would be appreciated